Azure AD Authentication redirects me to "{domain}/.auth/login/done" after "{domain}/.auth/login/aad/callback"?
I have an angular application deployed on Azure App Services and have enabled Azure's built-in authentication on it (aka Easy Auth). I am able to successfully login to my identity provider (AAD) but after being redirected to {domain}/.auth/login/aad/callback, I am again further redirected to {domain}/.auth/login/done. Any attempt to navigate back to the base URL just loops back around (since presumably whatever code or token produced hasn't been sent back to the application).
/done endpoint:

App registration redirect URIs:

Network request captured, showing the matching redirect URI:

Some more context: I only get this issue in the deployed instances. When building the front-end locally, the redirect URI is just set to localhost:4200 (defined in the SPA platform) and everything works as intended. However, just having {domain}/.auth/login/aad/callback under the "SPA" platform led to a PKCE error, so I followed this post and added both "web" and "single-page application" platforms.
I have seen the following posts but they appear to be doing some authentication on the server side:

Azure Active Directory always redirects to '~/.auth/login/done'
when deployed to Azure despite working on localhost
Web application with Azure Active Directory always redirects to the '~/.auth/login/done' URL


If you're using MSAL angular try disabling Azure's built in authentication for the client side apps in app services.

I created a simple Angular application with Azure AD and successfully deployed it to Azure App Service.

Make sure to configure your Azure Web App's URL in your app.module.ts and auth-config.ts as the redirectUri before deploying it to Azure App Service.

app.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  MsalModule,
  MsalInterceptor,
  MsalService,
  MSAL_INSTANCE,
  MsalGuard,
  MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
  MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
  MsalGuardConfiguration,
  MsalInterceptorConfiguration
} from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { PublicClientApplication, InteractionType } from '@azure/msal-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export function MSALInstanceFactory() {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: '<client-id>',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>',
      redirectUri: '<your-azure-web-app>',
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    },
  });
}
export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['user.read']
    }
  };
}
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap: new Map([
      ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
    ])
  };
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'translate', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    ]),
    MsalModule.forRoot(
      MSALInstanceFactory(),
      MSALGuardConfigFactory(),
      MSALInterceptorConfigFactory()
    )
  ],
  providers: [
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


auth-config.ts:
import { Configuration, BrowserCacheLocation, LogLevel } from '@azure/msal-browser';
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '<client-id>', 
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>', 
    redirectUri: '<your-azure-web-app>', 
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
    storeAuthStateInCookie: isBrowser && isIE(), 
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback(logLevel, message, containsPii) {
        if (containsPii) { 
          return; 
        }
        switch (logLevel) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
        }
      },
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
    }
  }
};
export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["User.Read"]
};
function isIE(): boolean {
  return isBrowser && (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 ||
      window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1);
}

app.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from  '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from  '@azure/msal-angular';
import { Router } from  '@angular/router';
@Component({
selector:  'app-root',
templateUrl:  './app.component.html',
})
export  class  AppComponent  implements  OnInit {
title(title:  any) {
throw  new  Error('Method not implemented.');
}
constructor(private  authService:  MsalService, private  router:  Router) {}
ngOnInit() {
this.authService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
next: (result) => {
if (result  !=  null  &&  result.account  !=  null) {
this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(result.account);
this.router.navigate(['/translate']);
}
},
error: (error) =>  console.log(error)
});
}
}


Make sure the Redirect URI in the Single-page application section matches the one in your code.



Configure the below startup command in the configuration section of the Azure Web App.

pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/my-angular-app/browser --no-daemon --spa


Here's the output after deployment:



